# How do I allow insecure connections on ios Testflight?

Tags: ios, security, network-programming, testflight

I would like to write a networked application for remote collaboration on ios. This is purely experimental/research-software. To test the application with multiple people, however, I will need to connect with local test servers and also servers on other machines that do not have SSL, certificates, etc. Those servers are on a university network though, so there are other security measures in place that I cannot control.
Apple has very strict policies, so I need to make sure that I can make the application I want at all without being flagged. 
How do I enable TCP AND UDP connections without those connections being blocked or the app being rejected from testflight? 
Exceptions for TCP seem documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections?language=objc).

I don’t see anything about UDP though.
Does anyone with experience beta testing using testflight know how to navigate this process and correctly program what needs to be in-place / fill the plist so TCP and UDP both work? (Implicitly I am also wondering what library to use. The regular bsd sockets?)

Note, I don’t intend to push research/prototype software to the app store. I realize that eventually I will need to care more about security. With the current outbreak situation, though, I need a fast way to build the test application under these constraints and be able to share with lots of people quickly.

Comment: ATS only applies to HTTPS connections through frameworks such as `URLConnection`.  If you use a low level socket framework, such as the `Network` framework then ATS rules are not enforced.  ATS does not apply to UDP as it is a datagram protocol.  In answer to which library to use, use the Network framework if you want connection oriented TCP and UDP sessions outside of HTTP, use `URLConnection` for HTTP.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do the apple testflight review people won’t block me from doing this? It’s unclear from the guidelines whether they’d allow it. Maybe I just need to explain in more detail? Is the Network framework different from the usual C library sockets? I’d like to hear more details in a full answer if you can provide one (also about the Network framework.) Also, as I recall, I need to support ipv6 (is that right?) even though I don’t need it. What is the easiest way to proceed?

Comment: TestFlight review is very lenient compared to App Store review. As long as the app doesn't actually crash as soon as you launch it, it will pretty much be approved for testing  Even with App Store review you don't have a problem with disabling ATS if you have a good reason.  The Network framework is documented here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network There are also lots of good WWDC videos from the last couple of years on the Network framework. I would expect a University network would be IPv6 addressable.

Comment: Also the Apple Reviewers will need to run your app from outside your network, so it must work via an Internet connection.

Comment: @Paulw11 Firstly, to confirm, IPV6 IS required for passing? Secondly, that's a problem. I can't give Apple access to private university servers. It's only meant for local host and temporary server spin-ups. I am not connecting with some always-on web-service. Again, it's meant for rapid prototyping. Actually I'm not sure if patch updates are fast enough for that. Is this dead-in-the-water then, or can I provide clarification?
I was also considering ad hoc distribution -- just add and remove people's devices to my account and avoid reviews altogether, but that also seems cumbersome.

Comment: Apple will test from an IPv6 network, so any required servers need to be accessible from that network. Once a version is approved for TestFliight (that takes about a day or two) updated builds in that version are available for testing immediately (it takes 10-20 minutes for Apple's upload processing) without review. If you can't provide Apple with a version that works for them to review then you could look at Microsoft AppCenter. It somewhat automates the collection of device identifiers for ad-hoc builds and testing.

Comment: @Paulw11 So only the server side would need to be configured for ipv6, and the client side would need to support some outgoing connection explicitly? Hopefully this isn't too challenging (is it)? I am not sure if my network actually supports ipv6, so I'm not sure how to test. Would I need some button on the client application that explicitly lets the user select the IP address type? Once I get that working, could I just specify a public IP (both ipv4 and ipv6) of the server to which the client can connect?

Comment: Apple will test your app from an IPv6 network. Here is their TechNote on testing it yourself - https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

Comment: @Paulw11 I suggest writing an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Paulw11 You might know the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920626/testflight-how-to-update-a-build-without-trigger-a-full-review